# how to pass .EXE and command line argument to cmd.exe from command button in visual basic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, cmd

I have .EXE file called (GPLCubist)that run using command line interface by passing argument like this
    GPLcubist  -f filesteamName 
where filesteamName is  the input file to the GPLcubist.exe.
Know i am going to design Interface using C# in visual basic community edition 2015.i need to pass the .EXE and the input to cmd.exe
I tried

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
           ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("GPLcubist.exe");
           startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
           Process.Start(startInfo);
           startInfo.Arguments = " -f filesteam";
}
```

please Any body Help me how to pass the GPLcubis.exe and the input file to CMD.exe using command button in visual basic.
thank you very much

Comment: You need to put the line `startInfo.Arguments = " -f filesteam";` before you call `Process.Start(startInfo);`

Comment: thank you very much  but -f filestem is the argument which is written in  CMD. so how could i open the cmd and pass .EXE and the input file

Comment: That's the way you do it. It will start the program and pass the arguments. No need to start a CMD.

Comment: thank you very much again. but is there a way to pass the path of the .exe   .

Comment: here is the error                                                                                    An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: That seems like the program you are trying to start isn't being found. Either put it in the same directory as your app or give full path to it.

Comment: please tell me that how do i give the .exe path

Comment: In the line `ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("GPLcubist.exe");` replace `"GPLcubist.exe"` with something like `System.IO.Path.Combine(rootDir, "GPLcubist.exe");` where `rootDir` is the directory where `GPLcubist.exe` is located.

Comment: System.IO.Path.Combine("E:\\MscThesis\\WorkingCubistCode\\GPLCubist.exe", "GPLcubist.exe");

Comment: i got similar error like before

Comment: `System.IO.Path.Combine("E:\\MscThesis\\WorkingCubistCode", "GPLcubist.exe");`

Comment: Still  similar error massage. Even though the program is actually present inside the specified path and the path is correct.

Comment: Btw: Your headline says Visual Basic, but your tags and code says C#

Answer (score 0):

You have to first define the arguments and than to start the process

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("GPLcubist.exe");
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    startInfo.Arguments = "-f filesteam"; // No need of the beginning space
    Process.Start(startInfo); // now start it with the startInfo
}
```

**Edit:**
Please note, that the last two lines were swapped.

Comment: Isn't it what I just said in the comment above? Why to post it as answer?

Comment: @dcg: Your comment was just a few seconds before my answer published. So I didn't see it before. But I agree with beardedmogul. An answer is an answer, that's Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks but the same ERROR:An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.

Comment: When do this error ocour? In the line `Process.Start(startInfo);`? Or do you try to modify the startInfo or the Process object after starting the process? Because this could cause this error.

Comment: I got the error after debugging and running the the project. when i try to pass the path and argument by pressing the command button that I already built in visual basic C#.

Comment: Sorry, but the error is not in the code above. Show us some more code and point to the exact position where the error occurs.

Comment: thank you: Here is my Question                                                                      i like to do this tricks when the  button in visual basic C#   is pressed                          1. first i have .EXE file which takes input data and generates Model when called in console (cmd.exe)  with command GPLcubist - f "Input data" .(It is necessary for input data and .EXE should be in the same directory) .                                                                    What i need to do is when the button from the visual basic C# is press i need the button to do this tricks.

Comment: Try this: Create a completely new empty windows forms project, add a button and add the code above to the click event. Everything should work. So your Problem is not in the code above!!